# Checking setSoTimeout for DatagramSocket() in Java

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I'm fairly new to java and I have a, probably, very easy question to answer.

I have a DatagramSocket and i have set the setSoTimeout to be around 2 seconds. I know from the Java library that if a recieve() is issued to this socket and 2 seconds passes and it doesn't recieve a reply, an exception is raised (java.net.SocketTimeoutException). Now for me, when this exception is raised, my entire client shuts down. I need a way to see if this exception has occurred and move to another section of my code rather than closing the entire client.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the line that throws `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` with `try/catch` block.

```
try {
  socket.receive(p);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
  ste.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific (like can you write the code you refer to)?